# Convert String -> byte[] -> String, not identity map

Tags: java, string, arrays

When I convert a String to a byte array and back to a String, I don't get the result I started with. Why is this?

```
String s1 = "" + (char)266;
String s2 = new String(s1.getBytes());
System.out.println(s1 + "|" + s2 + "|");
System.out.println((int)s1.charAt(0) + "|" + (int)s2.charAt(0));
```

Output:

```
?|?|
266 63
```

Comment: If you are using with eclipse IDE and your output is from eclipse's console , that is fine for me. You can also create `String` with charset parameter as `String s2 = new String(s1.getBytes(), Charset.forName("utf-8"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to lack the fundamental understanding of the relationship between a `char` and a `byte`.

**They are not interchangeable**.

WHen you have text, you have a stream of Unicode code points. It happens that in Java, `char` is used for this purpose. But for the process of decoding and encoding, they could very well be carrier pigeons.

So, you have text, and you have bytes. What you need to do is to be able to convert this text, aka this sequence of carrier pigeons (or `char`s, doesn't matter) into bytes (that's *encoding*), and then bytes back into text (that's *decoding*). In Java, both operations are available via a class which is called a `Charset`; as to the classes which perform those operations behind the scenes, those are a `CharsetEncoder` and a `CharsetDecoder`.

Therefore your program just cannot work. Also, when you use:

```
someString.getBytes()
```

you use the *default charset for your JRE/OS combination*. **Don't do that**. Always specify the charset when you encode or decode.

Comment: I don't quite follow your reasoning in concluding "your program just cannot work", but are you saying it wouldn't work even if I specify the charset? Because that's what I did (utf-8), and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Encoding and decoding are lossy; imagine you have a character in the original string which the current charset cannot handle; imagine what happens then.